# JOIN two tables by completed transaction

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to develop a protocolling in C# with a MS Access Database, which can be printed out by the user. I have different tables (Inventory,Lending,Returning) which can be seen here: 
[image: tables]

The idea is like this:

There is an **inventory** table (see Inventory on image), where there is a Product with a certain quantity.

And there are tables for a **lending process** (see Lending on image) with Datestamp:
"Jim is lending 3 Hammers on 01.01.2000 08:00"
etc.

and a **returning process** (see Returning on image) with Datestamp:
"Jim is returning 3 Hammers ..."
etc.

So i want to merge the two tables to create an overview of all completed transactions, where a completed transaction is lending & returning.

However, when i execute my code this is the **result** (see Result on image):

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = D:\Access\keymgt_db_test.mdb");
    oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Lending LEFT JOIN Returning ON Lending.EmployeeIndex=Returning.EmployeeIndex AND Lending.Datestamp<Returning.Datestamp", con);
    dta = new DataTable();
    oda.Fill(dta);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dta;
}
```

The desired result should look like **Ideal** (see image) in a dataGridView where duplicate IDs are prevented.

How can this be accomplished? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If this is an Access database, why the `mysql` tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems writing what should be a simple query (SQL DML) then you should suspect your design (SQL DDL).

It seems to me you have split apart a single entity (a lending period) across two rows.

The approach I have had most success with is to have `start_date` and `end_date` attributes on the same row. When the item is borrowed the `start_date` would be set to the current time-stamp value and the `end_date`, which hasn't happened yet, would be set to a far-future time-stamp value such as `#2099-12-31 23:59:59#` to signify infinity (a little like using `DateTime.MaxValue` in .NET but MS Access's `DATETIME` can't handle its precision).

This 'magic number' for infinity plays nice in code e.g.

```
...where now() between start_date and end_date
```

Formerly I used null (a rare exceptional case for me!) for the end date but found that more often than not I was having to handle the missing value! e.g.

```
...where now() between start_date and IIf(end_date IS NULL, #2099-12-31 23:59:59#, end_date )
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, I would also combine the `Lending` and `Returning` tables into a single `Transaction` table.

However, I understand that sometimes you really do want to have separate records for each side of a transaction. This gives you the ability to have much more complicated transactions... Alice lends to Bob, who lends to Charlie, who lends to David, who finally returns it to Alice. Each of those transactions has it's own record.

If you don't need these more complicated transactions, a single record with `LentFrom`, `LentTo`, `LentDate`, and `ReturnDate` columns will be good enough, and probably easier to implement and report from. But if you do want to support the more complicated transactions, you're back to separate records per change. Either way, get this down to one table.

Comment: Thanks Joel, i think this will be easier in programming a solution for preventing the duplicate IDs on the left side of the Result table. Question is: how could this solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answers from @onedaywhen and @Joel, you could combine the "Lending" and "Returning" tables into a single table but perhaps track each item individually. That is, instead of

```
ProductLent  LentTo  LentQty  DateLent
-----------  ------  -------  ----------
Hammer       Gord          3  2016-09-26
```

you could have

```
ProductLent  LentTo  DateLent    DateReturned
-----------  ------  ----------  ------------
Hammer       Gord    2016-09-26
Hammer       Gord    2016-09-26
Hammer       Gord    2016-09-26
```

That way if I only return one Hammer today then marking only one item as being returned is simply a matter of

```
ProductLent  LentTo  DateLent    DateReturned
-----------  ------  ----------  ------------
Hammer       Gord    2016-09-26  2016-09-27
Hammer       Gord    2016-09-26
Hammer       Gord    2016-09-26
```

(I see that you have hinted at such activity in your sample "Returning" table where Jim doesn't return all 5 Hammers at the same time.)

If you need to show a multi-item loan as a single "transaction" you could always run a query that COUNTs the individual rows GROUPed BY (ProductLent, LentTo, DateLent) to get the LentQty.

Such an approach might seem wasteful, but modern databases are really good at "rolling up" individual items and "rolling up" is almost always much easier than "splitting up" a single row into multiple rows. (As another example, consider a line-item on an Purchase Order where you order 5 units only to find that your supplier ships 3 units and puts the other 2 on backorder.)

Comment: Thanks Gord, i think i get your point. I thought about rolling up, but the protocolling demands, that each and every lending/returning is laid out with a datestamp. So the real problem is how to prevent the duplicate ID's on the left side of the Result table. I thought about building conditions to address specific rows until the transaction (lending+borrowing) is complete.